# What are the initial settings required to be done for mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2

What are the initial settings required to be done for mod_rewrite?

Asking this as I was unable to find a proper article.
*I think this question will be down-voted.*

Okay, To avoid getting down-voted,

I have these setting tried, but mod_rewrite doesn't seem to work:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so 

<Directory />
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<Directory "/mysite">
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All  # was suggested to do this from many sites.  
                       # So mod_rewrite could work
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    RewriteEngine On
</Directory>


<VirtualHost 'ip-addr'>
    .
    .
    .
    Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

---

```
httpd -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep rewrite
```

has the output:

```
 rewrite_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

---

My `DocumentRoot` is `/mysite`.
Have `xhprof` setup in `/mysite/xhprof`.

The `index` file to xhprof is in `/mysite/xhprof/xhprof_html`.

Have this in `/mysite/xhprof/xhprof_html/.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /xhprof
```

when I try to accesss `<myurl>/xhprof/xhprof_html/` the url does not get rewritten.

Comment: `I think this question will be down-voted.` I think that is an accurate perception. ;) You could prevent that from happening, though, by clarifying what you mean exaclty by "settings". What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pekka :) have added more details.

Comment: I do not see any RewriteRules defined in your .htaccess. What rewrite you expecting?

Comment: @UlrichPalha Ya, did know that.. Resolved it sometime back. This question is mute now. Although, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Include the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
```

Additionally, make sure that within your regular HTTP configuration (outside of `.htaccess`), you have an `AllowOverride` enabling whatever you need within `.htaccess`.  Either `AllowOverride FileInfo`, or `AllowOverride All` - depending upon your exact needs.

Comment: What's with the downvotes here - for both this answer and Miro's?  This accurately answered the question, "What are the initial settings required to be done for mod_rewrite?".  (There was no way to know that the RewriteRule's being expected weren't elsewhere within the configuration, and just not shown for conciseness...)

Answer (score -1):

You just have to turn it on by using this statement in .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
```

I recommend using a unix base editor (Notepad++ ,VM, ..) not the windows notepad because it adds unicode characters and may result in 500 Internal Server Error ... so if you got that error just copy what you wrote in htaccess and use a linux/unix based editor..

and If you are still getting 500 error then add this before RewriteEngine on :

```
IndexIgnore *
Options -Indexes
```